# How to block spoofed mail from *.host.com

Tags: postfix, spam, exim, spoofing

I'm currently running a centOS server with directadmin and custombuild.
I keep getting spoofed phishing mails with spoofed from addresses that have SPF setup properly.

Spamassassin gives it a score 1.8, probably because the mail seem legit and other tests compounded result in a negative score. So negative score + SPF test score = 1.8

In directadmin you have ways to block mail, but this is looking at the from address, not the mailserver that is spoofing.

All mails have these same sending mailserver headers:
Received: from cm17.websitewelcome.com (cm17.websitewelcome.com [100.42.49.20])
by gateway34.websitewelcome.com (Postfix)

IP addresses change and subdomains change.
But if I can somewhere block all mail from *.websitewelcome.com my problem is solved for a while.

Can I block this somewhere in Postfix or Exim?
Increasing SPF test score value is also an approach, but this can mark a lot of legit mails as well

Answer (score 1):

In Postfix you can block it directly on `smtpd(8)`.

According to http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html you can use

```
smtpd_client_restrictions - Reject all client commands
```

With it you can (http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_restrictions)

```
check_client_access type:table

Search the specified access database for the client hostname, parent domains, client IP address, or networks obtained by stripping least significant octets. See the access(5) manual page for details.
```

http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html contains example:

```
  /etc/postfix/main.cf:
           smtpd_client_restrictions =
               check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

and

```
/etc/postfix/access:
.websitewelcome.com REJECT
100.42.48.0/20 REJECT
```

(use `whois` to find network number and mask)

don't forget to call `postmap(1)`

Or you can block the whole IP network on your firewall, like

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT --src=100.42.48.0/20 -m tcp -p tcp --dport=25 -j DROP
```

Comment: If I whois websitewelcome.com I get an IP in USA and not in Rusland. So the subdomains get new IP ranges. So blocking IP is only effective for a short period

Comment: What about `smtpd_sender_restrictions` or `smtpd_helo_restrictions`? You can block on this level also

Answer (score 0):

Firewall block:

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -s ${BAD_IP} -j DROP
```

Block by header:

In /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
header_checks = /etc/postfix/header_checks
```

In /etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/From:\ .*baddomain\.tld/ DISCARD BAD AND STINKY DOMAIN
```

Run these commands

```
postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
systemctl restart postfix
```